# Manipulating index numbers

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation, statistics, price-index

I have a producer price index which is the composite of 9 various commodity prices including that of coal. I want to remove the effects of coal price changes from the original index. I have data on coal prices. Does anyone know of a method that I could use to filter out the effects of coal price changes from the original index?

Comment: $P_{agg}-P_{coal}Q_{coal}$?

Comment: Do you happen to know how the index is calculated (Paasche, Laspeyres, etc.), and the components (price changes, weights) for the individual components? Whether a particular method will work for your purposes depends on what information you have available to you.

Comment: @dismalscience I don't know the method, but what if the index is an unweighted average of the commodity prices?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is taking the index "ingredients" and rebuild it... assuming you manage the index data on a DB or on an excel file, that should not be too difficult

Otherwise, assuming you're index ingredients are averaged equally, then in a sense, the index is calculated as:

```
Index = (1 + Product1ChangeIn%)^(1/9) * (1 + Product2ChangeIn%)^(1/9) ...
```

So based on it, without coal, you're index should be:

```
Index / (1 + CoalChangeIn%)^(1/9)
```